# I am populating a text box with data from a select, it works, but

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

My select consists of two fields and the text field only picks up one of them. Here is my code:

```
 <script>
        function ProdValue(data) {
           document.getElementById("ProdName").value = data.value;
       }
 </script>

 <select name="ProdName" id="ProdName" onchange ="ProdValue(this)"> 
     <?php
             $sql = "Select * from tblProduct";
             if ($result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql));   
              while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) 
             { 
            echo "<option value='". $row['Brand']."', '".$row['ProductName']."'>".$row['Brand']." ".$row['ProductName']. '</option>';
            }
    ?>
</select>
```

How can I get ProductName too?

Answer (score 0):

Since your option `value` contains brand and productname separated by comma, you could do:

```
function ProdValue(data) {
   var optval = data,
   prod_name = optval.split(",")[1];
   console.log( prod_name ); //here is your product name
   document.getElementById("ProdName").value = optval;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use this instead. If both columns are actually defined as NOT NULL, CONCAT() will be quite enough:

```
 <?php
         $sql = "Select CONCAT(Brand, ProductName) as CombineColumn from tblProduct";
         if ($result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql))
         { 
               while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) 
               { 
               echo "<option value='". $row['CombineColumn']."'>".$row['CombineColumn']."</option>";
               }
          }
?>
```

Comment: You have two values that you have fetched from your table in one option, so rationally the document.getElementbyId() will get the first value it get and that's the Brand. So i think the solution is to CONCAT the data youre fetching for you to fetch the combined column/ textfield at the same time with one option value.

Comment: This did work but the problem is that I need to be able to separate the fields again and put them into two different text input fields and write them to the database. Is there any way I can use the concat with a non-printable character so I can parse the field out later? Or any other suggestions?

Comment: Does your text field contains any space between the brand and productname after you select a specific value in your combobox?